# Rails DB Schema: new, unique model or just an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord, associations

Im working on an Occasion Reminder rails app where users can register then set certain future dates and holidays/occasions that the app will remind them of via email in the future... Also, they can select interests and the emails will contain relevant deals to selected interests on those dates..

Anyways, my question is pretty simple in that I am setting up the initial models for the app and am wondering if the dates/holidays and then the interests should be attributes of the User model/table or unique models of their own (setting a has_many :interests association ect ect in the user model..)

Any ideas or suggestions very welcome!

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would lean toward separate models, especially for the interests. This allows you to easily query for them, and group the results to show various views of your data (e.g. find users with similar interests, or who might be going to the same event on a particular date). Separate models is also the 'correct' answer from a database normalization point of view.

It will be especially useful for your plan to offer deals based on the users' interests.

Comment: ok ya i agree that makes the most sense.. Im thinking about having a form letting the user select from about 20 "interests" so I would just have the interests table have a string like :self_interests ... thats all i would need to start ya?

Comment: I would set up the interests as a separate model with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with users. You can populate a set of initial interests, then add more in the future at your leisure.

Comment: thanks got it.. how would i populate the initial interests? and has_and_belongs_to_many only needs a join table with no model correct?

Comment: Initial interests can be populated by hand, with a migration, or by [seeding](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/5/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-database-seeding). and yeah, the `has_and_belongs_to_many` just needs a table without a model.